# Submit form with action="."

Tags: forms, spring, post

I am looking at an example from Spring In Practice. I have the following controller:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class AccountController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRegistrationForm(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("account", new AccountForm());
      return "users/registrationForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postRegistrationForm(AccountForm form) {
        LOG.info("Created registration: {}", form);
        return "redirect:/users/registration_ok.html";
    }
}
```

The URL "/main/users/new" in this controller creates a new AccountForm object and returns it to the view /main/users/registrationForm. Here is that jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>New user registration</title>
</head>
<body>
          <h1>New user registration</h1>

          <form:form cssClass="main" action="." modelAttribute="account">
          <p>All fields are required.</p>

          .... Form fields here ....

    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The book indicates to use action="." to post the form submission to /main/users. I am wondering if the reason action="." posts to /main/users is because this form was 'called' by a method in a controller mapped to /main/users and the "." specifies to post to this URL? The book does not explain this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` is a relative URI like any other; it points to the current “directory”. In `/main/users/new`, that’s `/main/users/`. `..` would be `/main/`.

Consider the case when the action is `create` instead; you’d end up with `/main/users/create`. `.` makes it `/main/users/.` According to [section 5.2.4 of RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4), that becomes `/main/users/`. (You can find a full description of every step in resolving a relative URI there, too.)